# Wildfly: Code changes aren't reflected in browser after deployment

Tags: javascript, deployment, server, jboss, wildfly

I am new to Wildfly, and deployment in general, so I apologize if this is a weird question. For a while now, I've been using Wildfly to deploy my application and haven't had any issues. However, recently, I started noticing that after a certain amount of time, changes made in my js files aren't reflected in the browser. I open the files up in the Chrome debugger tool and they aren't updated.

I read online that to solve this, I should shut down Wildfly and delete the tmp folder and then restart the server. When I did this in the beginning, files were being updated, but then I noticed it happened again, so I repeated the same steps. Every time, it seemed that issue would show up sooner and sooner, to the point where I can only deploy a few times before the issue comes back.

If someone can please give me any pointers, I'd really appreciate it. If I'm missing vital info in the question, please let me know so I can provide it. Thanks.

(I'm using Wildfly 24.0.0 Final in case that's important)

Comment: If you try and download that file with curl do you see the new version or the old?

Comment: You shouldn't have to delete the tmp file. How is your deployment deployed? Where do you update the JS?